# How to remove a post using update_user_meta()?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am loading articles as a list of ids in an input value:

```
$idThisPost = "19999";
<input id="input_post_id" type="hidden" name="varPostId" value="<?php echo $idThisPost; ?>">
```

Each article has a remove button:

```
<form id="saveId" action="" method="POST" class="" autocomplete="off">
    <input class="idsuser" type="hidden" name="save_post_value" value="<?php echo $userPosts; ?>"> 
    <button type="submit" class="removeJiku save_post btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
</form>
```

When we click the remove button, it should remove its id from the array and run an update on the custom field. Running the following gives me a string `Array` as a value.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['save_post_value'])) {
        $userPostsQuery = array_diff($userPostsQuery, array($_POST['save_post_value']));
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $userPostsQuery );
        $removed = $_POST['save_post_value'];
        unset($removed);
    }
}
```

Doing an explode like the following still gives me `Array` and not the actual `ids`

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
     if (isset($_POST['save_post_value'])) {
        $userPostsQuery = array_diff($userPostsQuery, array($_POST['save_post_value']));
        $userPostsQuery = explode(',', $userPostsQuery);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $userPostsQuery );
        $removed = $_POST['save_post_value'];
        unset($removed);
     }
 }
```

Comment: We would love to see `var_export($_POST['save_post_value'])` and probably `$userPostsQuery` too.  I don't see any `echo` where is the `Array` being printed from?  `update_user_meta()`?

Comment: @mickmackusa where would I put it? If I put inside the loop I get the same value like `19999`

Comment: I don't see any `loop` either.  I cannot recreate your issue.  If your `explode()` actually works, then `$userPostsQuery` is a comma-separated string (not an array -- which `array_diff()` is expecting).  Have you checked your error logs?  Show me some sample data please.  Your code is definitely "broken" I just don't know how early to start correcting.

Comment: @mickmackusa basically I am looping in order to get the articles, and the code above is what I have inside each loop

Comment: I think you have to unset($userPostsQuery[$removed]); this is what removes the element from the array where you save post id-s (I guess this is the array name $userPostsQuery)

Comment: Regarding second attempt with explode.... `$userPostsQuery = explode(',', $userPostsQuery);` is trying to explode an array made from `array_diff`. Explode expects a string (to turn into an array). Implode expects an array (to turn into a string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $userPostsQuery );` call is expecting `$userPostsQuery` to be a string, but you are delivering an array.  You can convert the array to a comma-separated string like this:

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', implode(',', $userPostsQuery) );
```

And place your entire deletion block immediately after you declare `$userPostsQuery` so that subsequent processes are using the updated database data.

Furthermore `if (isset($_POST['save_post_value'])) {` sufficiently checks for a the submitted data, so `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {` can be omitted entirely.

And

```
$removed = $_POST['save_post_value'];
unset($removed);
```

is only getting rid of `$removed`, perhaps you want `unset($_POST['save_post_value']);` but I'm not sure if it's needed at all.